# Как правильно объединить два столбца и сделать по нему JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Всем привет!
У меня есть две таблицы:
Мои друзья(friends): id, user1_id, user2_id, joined
Пользователи(users): id, name, sename

Хочу достать значение из поля user1_id и user2_id объединить их в один столбец, и уже по этому столбцу сделать INNER JOIN с таблицей users.

С объединением проблем не возникло, делаю так:

```
SELECT user1_id as friend_id, joined
FROM friends
WHERE user2_id = 7 #Выбираем всех друзей пользователя из второй колонки
UNION
SELECT user2_id, joined
FROM friends
WHERE user1_id = 7 #Выбираем всех друзей пользователя из первой колонки
```

А вот JOIN никак не могу подружить с union. Делаю так:

```
SELECT users.*, friends.user1_id as friend_id, friends.joined
FROM users
INNER JOIN friends
ON friends.friend_id = users.id
WHERE friends.user2_id = 7
UNION
SELECT user2_id, joined
FROM friends
WHERE user1_id = 7
```

В двух словах:
Друзья пользователя могут находится в колонке friends.user1_id или friends.user2_id, чтобы упростить запрос я хочу объединить эти две колонки и уже по этой колонке достать нужных пользователей из таблице users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT users.*, friend_id, joined
FROM(
  SELECT user1_id as friend_id, joined
  FROM friends
  WHERE user2_id = 7 #Выбираем всех друзей пользователя из второй колонки
  UNION
  SELECT user2_id, joined
  FROM friends
  WHERE user1_id = 7 #Выбираем всех друзей пользователя из первой колонки
)friends
  INNER JOIN users
    ON friends.friend_id = users.id
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Все работает

Comment: @QWERTY, a куда оно денется:)